# Does the orderer store all the blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Does the orderer always store all the blockchain (not the World State)?

Is it possible to configure the Orderer to not to keep the blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

The orderer service must store the ledger to order the blocks correctly. Because Fabric’s design relies on deterministic consensus algorithms, any block a peer validates as generated by the ordering service is guaranteed to be final and correct.

Comment: Well, I was told from a college that there's a option where it's possible to configure the Orderer to maintaint just the last blocks in memory, and not the entire blockchain on disk. I want to check if it's really true, because I didn't find it anywhere in documentation.